# How to display source code in html webpage?

Tags: html

I want to display this code in html page.

```
<html>
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <title>Document</title>
       </head>
         <body>
           <p>some text</p>             
         </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: On Web-Browser you can Right Mouse Click and Inspect Element. Hope this will help you.

Comment: replace  < by &lt;  and > by &gt;  (ie:  &lt;html&gt;  would print <html> on the browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Good Evening

Some characters are reserved in HTML and they have special meaning when used in HTML document. For example, you cannot use the greater than and less than signs or angle brackets within your HTML text because the browser will treat them differently and will try to draw a meaning related to HTML tag.

There are some special characters in html to add < and > otherwise browser will take it as tags.

```
&lt; for <
&gt; for >
```

**So your code goes this way**

```
&lt;html&gt;
 &lt;html lang="en"&gt;
   &lt;head&gt;
     &lt;title&gt;Document&lt;/title&gt;
       &lt;/head&gt;
         &lt;body&gt;
           &lt;p&gt;some text&lt;/p&gt;             
         &lt;/body&gt;
 &lt;/html&gt;
```

> Hope it helped you

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i know this way of coding however when i inspect the stackoverflow website they didn't use &lt; , &gt;  i just want to know how do they show these codes in their page? because i have to use on my website.

Comment: Actually You are Wrong. stackOverflow also uses this only. I have checked it by inspecting also. Your question is like this when I checked -                                        
  <pre><code>&lt;html&gt;
 &lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot;&gt;
   &lt;head&gt;
     &lt;title&gt;Document&lt;/title&gt;
       &lt;/head&gt;
         &lt;body&gt;
           &lt;p&gt;some text&lt;/p&gt;             
         &lt;/body&gt;
 &lt;/html&gt;
</code></pre>

Comment: And it is the only way to do this. Believe me ◀️

Answer (score 0):

the way to do this is by replacing:

- '<' with "&lt"
- '>' with "&gt"

An example of this would look like this :

```
<p> A paragraph <a/>
```

Would then be

```
&lt;p&gt: A Paragraph &lt;/p&gt;
```